# understand the designation of symbolic links

Tags: symlink, ln

I have a number of files in `/etc/rc3.d/` directory which all are symbolic links and point to files in `/etc/init.d/` directory using `../init.d/` designation. For example file `S18rsyslog` in `/etc/rc3.d/` directory is a symbolic link to file `/etc/init.d/rsyslog`, but according to `ls -l`, `/etc/rc3.d/S18rsyslog` does not point to `/etc/init.d/rsyslog` but `../init.d/rsyslog` instead:

```
# ls -l /etc/rc3.d/S18rsyslog
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 30. jun 15:05 /etc/rc3.d/S18rsyslog -> ../init.d/rsyslog
#
```

What is the advantage to keep symbolic links relative to directory? Because this allows one to move the direcoty itself without breaking the symbolic links? In addition, is it possible to create a symbolic link with `..`(parent directory) in the path without being in the directory? `ln -sv '/etc/init.d/rsyslog' '/etc/rc3.d/../init.d/rsyslog'` obviously does not work as symlink is created into `/etc/init.d/` directory while I would like to have symlink named `../init.d/rsyslog` in the `/etc/rc3.d/` directory.

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't my symbolic link work?](//superuser.com/q/511900/354511)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the advantage to keep symbolic links relative to directory? Because this allows one to move the direcoty itself without breaking the symbolic links?

Exactly.

> In addition, is it possible to create a symbolic link with `..` (parent directory) in the path without being in the directory? `ln -sv '/etc/init.d/rsyslog' '/etc/rc3.d/../init.d/rsyslog'` obviously does not work as symlink is created into `/etc/init.d/` directory while I would like to have symlink named `../init.d/rsyslog` in the `/etc/rc3.d/` directory.

So you mean to express `ln -s ../init.d/rsyslog /etc/rc3.d`

In order to not slip on symlinks it is best to keep in mind that `ln` has the semantic of `ln TARGET LINK` and that a symlink is in essence a file at LINK that contains TARGET; if TARGET is a relative pathname, then TARGET substitutes the symlink relative to its containing directory.  Thus, `ln -s X/Y A/B/` becomes `A/B/X/Y`.

Comment: Thanks! I think I forgot how to compute when I wrote this `ln -sv '/etc/init.d/rsyslog' '/etc/rc3.d/../init.d/rsyslog'` :)